# android listview intent

Tags: android, android-listview

I am not able to create an intent after click in my Listview. After completing It gives an error

> The application has stopped unexpectedly, please try again

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
     Intent IntentDiscution = new Intent(view.getContext(), lstchoi.class);
     IntentDiscution.setClass(InterfaceAcceuil.this, lstchoi.class);
     startActivityForResult(IntentDiscution, 0);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the logcat output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declared `lstchoi` in your manifest.xml.  Assuming it is an Activity, you would do something like:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".lstchoi"/>
```

You can also remove this line:

```
 IntentDiscution.setClass(InterfaceAcceuil.this, lstchoi.class);
```

It is redundant because you used the constructor to indicate the same information.