# android listview intent

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android listview intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005309/android-listview-intent)

I am not able to create an intent after click in my Listview. After completing It gives an error The application has stopped unexpectedly, please try again. My class ListActivityImage extends ListActivity

```
 Intent IntentDiscution = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListActivityImage.class);
          startActivityForResult(IntentDiscution, 0);
```

Comment: Have you defined `ListActivityImage` in your manifest. Log cat will better help us to find the problem

Comment: Please stop asking duplicate questions. If you want to add more information, just edit your question.

Comment: LogCat message 08-18 04:05:05.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(918):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: My class extends ListActivity

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
Intent IntentDiscution = 
 new Intent(ListActivityImage.this.getApplicationContext(), ListActivityImage.class);
startActivityForResult(IntentDiscution, 0);
```